# Search across two different databases (mysql and postgres)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Is it possible to search for something that is in two databases? For example, I want to do a "starts with" search on a column in Postgres as well as a column in MySQL where one is "name" and one is "email"

Copying over data is not reliable as new data will be created in both databases constantly.

Comment: `LIKE` might be able to handle your searching logic, as it supports "starts with."  Add some sample data to your question for best results here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. For the "starts with" part, you should be able to use the standard *Postgres* [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html), of which `starts_with` is one, and [indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) on the desired columns.

Getting the data from *MySQL* is the more complicated part.

You would most likely want to use a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) (e.g. FDW) from *Postgres* to access the *MySQL* data, and then handle the unioning of it (or other desired processing) with the *Postgres* data for returning the combined data set.

You could write your own FDW if you have particularly specific requirements, or you could try an open source one, such as [this one](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) from EnterpriseDB. EnterpriseDB is a Postgres consultancy and offers their own Postgres version, but the doc on the Github page for this says it is compatible with base Postgres as well as their own version.